# Why is the video color messed up in our California Speed arcade cabinet?

Tags: hardware, arcade, california-speed

A friend of mine recently acquired a California Speed arcade machine.
The controls work, but the monitor is not the original. It uses a CGA to VGA converter to get the video to display on the new monitor.

The color in the video for the game is messed up though. It's mostly red and white, but sometimes it shows up with all colors working properly. Anything else hooked up to the monitor is great though.

What could be wrong?

Comment: While I don't think this is off-topic, I think that OP would be more likely to receive a detailed answer on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ because they have more experience with tinkering.